# Generate an ID from input - Javascript or Jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I've spent a few hours looking for a solution to this, but no joy.
So...

I'd like to generate IDs based on the input. For example across a whole website;

```
<p class ="dynamic">I like cheese</p>
The outcome would be...
<p id ="i_like_cheese" class ="dynamic">I like cheese</p>
```

basically, whatever the text is, the id will mirror that. Any advice on where to start would be really appreciated!

Comment: look for jquery onChange and jquery attr.

Comment: This is a very bad idea. It feels like a scenario where you are trying to achieve thing A and think you can do it by thing B but get stuck to you ask about thing B rather than how to achieve the intended goal A.  You might want to look up the [requirements for an ID](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id)  and see the note about starting with a letter and using a specific range of characters - how will you police that in the inputs that provide the id's? How will you work with Unicode characters, yada yada yada.  Overall this is not a worthy question for SO.

Comment: @VanquishedWombat *XY Problem* is the term you're looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) to get all elements with class `dynamic` then loop on each `p` and set `id` from [`innerText`](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/innerText) in wich you previsouly replace spaces by '_' with [`replaceAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replaceAll)

```js
let ps = document.querySelectorAll('.dynamic');
ps.forEach(p=>{
p.id = p.innerText.replaceAll(' ','_');
console.log(p.id)
})
```

```html
<p class ="dynamic">I like cheese</p>
<p class ="dynamic">I dont like cheese</p>
```

Comment: Always a good idea to check your code's output... did you mean `.replaceAll`?

Comment: I was editing when you post. My bad.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for all the suggestions and feedback. The solution I have implemented was from BZezzz.

```
let ps = document.querySelectorAll('.dynamic');
ps.forEach(p=>{
p.id = p.innerText.replaceAll(' ','_');
console.log(p.id)
})
```

A few people suggested the use case for this was a bad idea, so wanted to elaborate on what I've used this in conjunction with.

A WordPress plugin called "Table of Content" creates a TOC with anchor points a href="/#i-like-cheese"

I wanted to target specific elements on the page that would then populate the TOC anchor points as the plugin did not have all the functionality I required.

Comment: *"...WordPress..."* say no more...

Answer (score 0):

seems like a horrible idea... but

```js
$( "p.dynamic" ).each(function() {
var newStringForID = $( this ).text();
var newID = newStringForID.replace(/\s+/g, '_').toLowerCase();
  $( this ).attr( "id", newID );
  console.log('dynamix ID set to '+newID )
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="dynamic">test 1</p>
<p class="dynamic">test 2</p>
<p class="dynamic">test 2 with more text </p>
<p class="dynamic">test 3</p>
<p class="dynamic">test4  gfdsg gfd </p>
<p class="dynamic">test5 <span>test</span></p>
<p class="dynamic">test6 <a href="#link">Link</a></p>
<p class="dynamic">test7</p>
<p class="dynamic">test8</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function nw_store_variable(ele) {

  let newVariable = ele.value;
  let st = ' ';
  let regX = new RegExp(st, "gim");
  // return this.newVariable.description;
  let strippedSpace = newVariable.replace(regX, '_');
  let properCase = strippedSpace.toLowerCase();
  let removerepeatedUndrScr = properCase.replace('--', '_'); //replace with recursive in future

  let e = document.querySelector('.dynamic');
  console.log(e)

  e.id = removerepeatedUndrScr;
  return
}
```

```html
<p class="dynamic">

  <input onkeyup="nw_store_variable(this)"> I like cheese</p>
The outcome would be...
<p class="dynamic">I like cheese</p>
```

Comment: *replace with recursive in future* - or use a regex or `.replaceAll`

Comment: means what . will u explain ?

Comment: *Your* comment is "replace with recursive *in future*" - you can use a regex or just `.replaceAll` instead of `.replace`

Answer (score 0):

Use querySelectorAll to filter your DOM element by class name,

```
var lst = document.querySelectorAll('.dynamic')
```

Iterate through all the elements of the returned list, and set the id with respect to valid characters in the inner text of the HTML element. At this level, however, you must take into consideration the HTML version (4 or 5), because naming conventions differ between versions 4 and 5.

**Version4:** (https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#type-id)
ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"), underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").

**Version5:** (https://www.w3.org/TR/html5-author/global-attributes.html#the-id-attribute)
The id value must not contain any space characters.

To be on the safe side, I will assume that your website uses HTML4, and proceed accordingly.

```
//use regex to validate input with respect to HTML4 specifications
function isIdValid(id) {
  let re = new RegExp(/^[A-Za-z]+[\w\-\:\.]*$/);
  return re.test(id);
}

var counterID = 1;
function generateuuid() {
  return "id_" + counterID.toString();
  counterID+=1;

}

var lst = document.querySelectorAll('.dynamic');
lst.forEach(htmlelem => {
  if (isIdValid(htmlelem.innerText.replaceAll(' ', '_'))) {
    htmlelem.id = htmlelem.innerText.replaceAll(' ', '_');
  }
  else {
    htmlelem.id = generateuuid();
    //another approach would be to remove invalid characters from the inner 
    //text, and assign the value to htmlelem.id but this has a performance 
    //drawback,  because it would require looping over each character.

  }
})
```